# Matplotlib - Creating a new graph from event data

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling

I have a scatter graph that displays an annotation as the mouse hovers a point. I want to add a button_press_event event that, when the user clicks on a point, will put the corresponding selected `r[2]` string and put it inside the `wordChosenList` array and recreate the scatter graph with correct annotations. For that, I need to know 2 things:

1. How do I access the corresponding selected `r[2]` string from inside `newScatter()`
2. I've tried to set `r` as constant data and was able to get a new graph out of my code. However, I was lacking all of the annotations. How do I get them for the new data?
3. That newScatter method would need to be able to execute on the graph with the new datas as well.

P.S.: Do not worry about `generateData(wordChosenList)`, it returns a 2D list of length 4 (similar to the first line)

```
r = [[1,2,3][4,5,6],[5,5,5],["a","b","c"]]

wordChosenList = []
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
occurences=[[],[],[]]

sc = plt.scatter(r[0],r[1],c='#74DF00',edgecolors='#07190B', s=r[2], alpha=0.5)
annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0,0), xytext=(20,20),textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)

def update_annot(ind):

    pos = sc.get_offsets()[ind["ind"][0]]
    annot.xy = pos
    text = "word: {}\n".format(" ".join([r[3][n] for n in ind["ind"]]))
    annot.set_text(text)
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_facecolor('#F6CECE')
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.4)

def update_wordList(ind):
    wordChosenList.append(names[range(len(ind["ind"]))])

def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()

    if event.inaxes == ax:
        cont, ind = sc.contains(event)
        if cont:
            update_annot(ind)
            annot.set_visible(True)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        else:
            if vis:
                annot.set_visible(False)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()

def newScatter(event):
    r = generateData(wordChosenList)
    plt.clf()
    sc = plt.scatter(r[0],r[1],c='#74DF00',edgecolors='#07190B', s=r[2], alpha=0.5)
    annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0,0), xytext=(20,20),textcoords="offset points", bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"), arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
    annot.set_visible(False)
    plt.draw()


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', newScatter)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)

plt.show()
plt.draw()
```